# Does the phrase 'die in surprise' exist?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

In my country, when people surprised so much we speak:

> I almost died in surprise.

When you get astonished so much, you feel a bit of pain in your heart. And you feel you might die from it.

But I don't get any google hit with the phrase 'die in surprise'.
I searched also 'die on surprise', 'die by surprise', and 'die from surprise'.
I don't get any google hit on the first page.

Do you use this expression? If not, what would be the closet thing to this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got close, but the phrase in English uses "of".
[Google search "die of surprise"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=%22die%20of%20surprise%22)

For example: "I might die of surprise..."

Comment: Thanks! I was lack of imagination a bit.